# What is the difference between these import statements?

Tags: python, methods, import

I have seen many online examples with different ways of `import`ing modules. I was wondering what the difference is, if it is in speed, accuracy, priority, or psychology.

The first, and most common is;

```
import sys
import os
import socket
import shutil
import threading
import urllib
import time
import zipfile
```

I understand the methodry, but this seems unnecessary when you can use, like I personally do;

```
import sys, os, socket, shutil, threading, urllib, time, zipfile
```

Less lines, less code, less headaches, at least in my opinion. However, the third one stumps me;

```
import sys, os, shutil
import threading
import zipfile
import socket, urllib
import time
```

What is the point or purpose of that method of importing? I would think that it would be inconvenient to mix the first two methods, as well as cluttered. It also seems like it would be slower than either method, or in worst case scenario, slower than both combined.

So, like I was wondering, what's the difference between the three?

Is there any logic in the third one, like a speed increase, or is it just for looks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functionally, they do the same thing. It's a style preference. Many people adhere to the PEP-8 style guidelines (ref: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) which state that imports should be on separate lines.

Comment: Thanks for the resource, however, that only states what is good and what is bad, not why it is good, why it is bad, and why not to use it. Thank You for the reply!

Comment: That's because one is not objectively better or worse; it's a style guide, not a rule book. There are definitely some perks that come with it: it's much easier to see changes to imports if they are on multiple lines when using version control such as git.

Comment: I just marked your question as the answer since it seems your answer is the best there will be. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The third one groups packages that are likely to be used together.
When you're copying headers (set-up code) from one file to another, this method makes it easier to choose exactly the set of imports you need for the new program.